# Textbox textChanged event withount enabling postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

I have webpage with many textboxes. I want to call a function (CalcBalance) on TextBox_TextChanged event. This works well with textbox's Postback set to true, but this makes the app not to be user friendly because when the user scrolls down to use other textboxes, the "postback" keeps taking the user to the top of the page. i.e. the user will have to scroll down after changing the text in any textbox.

Is there any way I can call this function without enabling postback?

Comment: In general, no. But what does this function at all? Maybe you could use a webmethod (or [`jQUery`-Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)). Another way, set [`MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` or use ASP.NET-Ajax. Why can't you let the user enter the text into all textboxes before he clicks a submit-button? This is the way i would use.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter. I'll try the first two suggestions. I can't let the user enter text into all textboxes before they click a button becuase the function calculate balances and sub totals of sections of a big budget that the user need to see before saving, for neccessary balancining the expences with income. In this way I am able to notify the user is the budgeted total is greater than the maximum posible amount (Calculated by percentages of total income). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Schmelter. The easiest way was to put this line:
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = "true" in the function (CalcBalance).